# Connect via PoE an access point D-Link DAP-2610 using PoE out port of a Mikrotik Hex S

Tags: router, access-point, power-over-ethernet

I have just bought an access point D-Link DAP-2610 and it does not come with a power supply so I want to power it via PoE using eth5 of my Mikrotik Hex S.

When I plug in my device, RouterOS in Winbox says that PoE out status is powered on but zero connection and AP led light is powered off. eth5-POE out light port in my router is red.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask about those on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the D-Link DAP-2610 support POE (802.3af), the [Mikrotik Hex S.](https://mikrotik.com/product/hex_s#fndtn-specifications) support only passive POE, which is not a standard.

So it doesn't start the negotiation the AP wait for and this cannot work.

Comment: So it is impossible to use it configuring anything then, only alternative is using PoE inyector or a power supply?

Comment: @ÁngelCarlosdelPozoMuela There may be a setting on the Mikrotik router to set the port in a specific power state that the access point will recognize but I never used Mikrotik and I avoid D-Link devices.